# Variable assignment in .bash_profile has no effect

Tags: bash, environment-variables, profile

I added the following to my `.bash_profile`:

```
JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0
export JAVA_HOME
```

However, when I `echo $JAVA_HOME` it outputs an empty string. Why weren't my changes to `.bash_profile` reflected in the shell?

Comment: Have you logged in again since the editing of `~/.bash_profile`? `~/.bash_profile` is executed only when a login shell or `bash --login` is started.

Comment: @manatwork Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, I am not so sure. Can not remember ever seeing `JAVA_HOME` set to a _list_ of paths. I have a bad feeling regarding its correctness, so I prefer not to participate in this, beyond a simple comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your *.bashrc* file, if you want it set for every interactive *shell*.